# Use odbc eloquent outside laravel PHP7

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I am using eloquent outside laravel. I have my own PHP application.
This is what i am using https://github.com/illuminate/database

My config is as following

```
$settings3 = array(
'driver'    => 'odbc',
'dsn' => "Driver={SQL Server};Server={serverName};Trusted_Connection=true;Database=telesur_mis;",
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'user',);

$capsule->addConnection($settings3,'teleappframework');
```

After executing this code I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported driver [odbc]

I have PDO ODBC installed, i have also tested pdo odbc connection outside of eloquent.
The reason for using ODBC is, because i am using PHP7 and currently there is no PDO extension for SQL Server.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: Version 5, I am using this library https://github.com/illuminate/database
I am only using the ORM tool of laravel

Comment: Have configured "odbc" inside your laravel properly? Is it working fine inside?

Comment: How should i do that? the code that I have used is in the OP. I don't know if thats the correct way.

If I look in the connection factory of Illuminate database, then i do not see ODBC in it.
https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php

Answer (score 0):

i would download FreeTDS and just use the regular sqlsrvr driver it works like a charm (if you are on a unix env) there is a lot of posts on how to configure it etc just look it up.

Comment: The regular sql server driver will not work with eloquent right, it uses PDO?

Comment: it does use pdo, i apologize i did not pay attention to the php7 part yes theres no pdo extension for the php7. i ran into that issue and ended up reverting back to php 5.6 @Wishaal

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>PHP7</kbd> has a few modules disabled by default that were previously enabled in <kbd>PHP5</kbd>.

Most likely running `php -m` does not show the modules you need.

It's an easy fix though since the extension should already exist in the `\ext\` folder that came with <kbd>PHP7</kbd>. You just need to modify your `php.ini` file to include the line:

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

Then from a command prompt or terminal test again using `php -m` to see that the module is now listed.